# Giving Titles to side plots in Shiny with Fluidrow

Tags: r, shiny, shinydashboard

How to give titles in Shiny for two side plots, I am trying to do something like following, which is definitely giving me error

```
shinyUI(
 titlePanel("Hello Shiny!"),
 mainPanel(
 fluidRow(
 splitLayout(cellWidth(50%,50%),
  tableOutput("Table1", tags$b("Title1")),
  plotOutput("Plot",tags$b("Title2)))))
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is the solution for you:

```
    library(shiny)

        ui <- basicPage(
  fluidRow(
    column(6,box("Title 1",tableOutput("Table1"))),
    column(6,box("Title 2",plotOutput("Plot")))))

server <- function(input, output) {
}

shinyApp(ui, server)
```

It is enough if you just type the text in `column` container before `..output(..)`

I have improved bit your code by replacing `splitLayout()` to `column` containers which divide/split the `ui` into two, same size containers (`column(6)`=50%) and addition of `box()`, so your `outputs` are held there and title will be attached to it (to the `box`)

Comment: I tried this solution but "Title 2" appears before the plot does. Is there a solution that allows "Title 2" to appear when the plot does?